# PHP : Trying to display a PDF document

Tags: php, pdf

I'm working on a web application with files saved on the server. How can I display the PDF file using php?

**Attempt #1 :**

$psFilePath looks like : I:/www/wwwpasroot/netclinic/dev/csst/PE1000054684 - Version1.pdf

```
echo "<embed src='$psFilePath' type='application/pdf'   height='300px' width='100%'>";
```

Result : Not allowed to load local resource: file:///I:/www/

**Attempt #2** :

```
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$psFileName");
    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s')." GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0");
    header("Pragma: anytextexeptno-cache", true);
    header("Cache-control: private");
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    $filesize = filesize($psFilePath);
    if( file_exists ( $psFilePath ) && is_readable( $psFilePath ) )
    {
        $handle = fopen($psFilePath, "r");
        $contents = fread($handle, $filesize);
        fclose($handle); 
        echo $contents; 
    }
```

Result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqdhH.jpg

Seems like #2 is more promising but the content is still not displaying correctly. Am I doing something incorrectly? I've tried changing the "header" options with no success

Thank you!

EDIT :

Attempt #3 : `With <a></a>`

```
echo "<a href='$psFilePath'>PDF</a>";
```

Result ; not allowed to load local ressource

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php

$file = 'file.pdf';

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $file . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

@readfile($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

I needed to put the PDF inside an iframe!

```
<iframe src='link_to_my_controller/ShowPDF'></iframe>
```

And then my controller call the method to do the readfile!